# Beef suet in fridge

Tags: food-safety, beef, refrigerator

How long is beef suet good in fridge?

Does it make any difference if I store it as a whole or chopped into pieces?

EDIT: This is suet, not tallow, which can even be left outside the fridge for 1 year. This *not* a duplicate question.

EDIT: Suet is raw fat not raw protein.

Comment: I saw your edit now, I had mixed up the English terms for suet and tallow. I now added a second duplicate target, just look up "raw protein" there, it applies to all raw meat products, including the fat.

Comment: Raw protein is not raw fat. Could you remove the duplicate tag on this please? Evidently none of your alternative URLs actually answer my question.

Comment: It doesn't matter that raw protein is not raw fat. The guidelines are the same for every part of a slaughtered animal without cooking. It is just called "raw protein" in the other question for convenience.

Comment: Sorry, this is most unhelpful response. The other question does not deal with unrendered fat (like suet) at all, and in some places they have stored suet for longer than what the guideline recommend for animal *protein*: https://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18437 

So my question is still valid. I understand you are doing the 'janitor' job of Stackoverflow, but you should also know when to make exceptions to general rules instead of rigidly sticking to them.

Answer (score 0):

I usually store suet in the freezer, where it keeps for many months.  In the fridge, I wrap it carefully to reduce oxygen exposure (and hence, rancidity).

Comment: How long do you think it lasts in the fridge ?